# Unable to reference all Model objects in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an odd problem whereby the model in my vbhtml file will correctly reference and bring up the model's attributes for 1 item but not for another.
FYI, The page is added as a partial page, connected to another vbhtml page.

My page is structured such that I want to list a number of people (beneficiaries), below each question (question text).

I am referencing my Model type using the syntax: @ModelType RHEAL_START.QuestionWithAnswers, so this should automatically allow the model items to be declared when instantiated.

The @ModelType declaration correctly allows the referencing of the 2nd model field (Model.benAnswers) but not the first one I have declared (Model.questionText).

Both items are part of the same model and, I have tried moving the declarations above and below the  and  headers but, this did not bring up an IntelliSense for the Model.questionText.

I looked at the following post and tried addding in a reference to the Layout file but alas, this did not bring up an IntelliSense either.
[MVC3 - render view that is not a method in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346274/mvc3-render-view-that-is-not-a-method-in-a-controller)

See the code below. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong and what else I can try?
If you need more information, please let me know.

```
@ModelType RHEAL_START.QuestionWithAnswers
@Code
    Layout = "~/Views/MedicalQuestions/MedicalQuestions.vbhtml"
End Code
    <div id="questionPanel">
        @Code 
            Dim qAndARef As Integer = 0
        End Code

            <!-- Show question text and number -->
            <h1><a href="#">Model.questionText</a></h1>

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        Beneficiary </td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        Yes/No </td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        Details </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- !!Iterating over each beneficiary for Medical Question -->

                @For Each benanswer As RHEAL_START.BeneficiaryAnswer In Model.benAnswers

                Html.Partial("../MedicalQuestions/BeneficiaryAnswerPartial", benanswer)

                Next
            </table>


        @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@

    </div>

@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/RHEAL/YesNoDropDownValidation.js")
End Section
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see how the model class is defined

Comment: _offtopic:_ you can use razor comments (`@* *@`) instead of HTML comments (`<!-- -->`). This way, your comments will not be visible on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the VB syntax for Razor, but it looks like you're missing a @ sign in front of `@Model.questionText`

Comment: A colleague suggested that in the office this morning and that's what I tried. It solved the problem. Thanks